# Could someone tell me what is going on here

Tags: python

So I have a code:

```
l = [1,2,3,34]
for l[1] in l:
    pass
print(l)
```

for some reason, l would be [1,34,3,34]
I am not quite sure what is happening here.

Comment: You overwrite `l[1]` in your loop. The last iteration sets `l[1]` to `34`. Replace `pass` with `print(l)` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Think of:

```
for l[1] in l:
    pass
```

as

```
for x in l:
    pass
```

where `l[1]` is bound one after the other to all the values the loop variable `x` would take. Here, these are the elements of `l`. And the last one sticks! Hence, `l[1]` is set to `34` by the loop.

This becomes even more evident if you do:

```
for l[1] in l:
    print(l[1])

1
1
3
34
```

where you can see that the first iteration sets the second element (`l[1]`) to the first one. All subsequent iteration then override `l[1]` with the next element.

Answer (score 0):

man I should advise you to name your variable properly. Try out to check the zen of python and practice 'readability counts'.
okay, if your trying to use a for loop to print each item then try this
l = [1,2,3,34]
for item in l:
    print(item)

Answer (score 0):

it's like you are setting l[1] to the item you are iterating throw in the list and the last item is 34 so l[1] value is 1 in the first iteration and again 1 in the second 3 in the third and 34 in the last and it's how the final answer is  [1,34,3,34]

Answer (score 0):

As I see things, in this loop, you've chosen an element in the list and have substituted it by the last element in the same list. I come up with another example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,61]
for l[3] in l:
    pass
print(l)
```

The following list printed afterward:

```
[1, 2, 3, 61, 5, 61]
```

As you see the 4th element has been substituted by the last element in the list.